# When I split an ArrayList of Strings by # the last field is incorrect

Tags: java, string, text, split

New to java here. I'm trying to split a string into variables in an object. As the title says the last field in the string splits together with the first field.

A line from my txt file all the other lines are identical.

Here's the output:

```
Rolling Stone#Jann Wenner#Bi-Weekly#Boston#9000
Rolling Stone#Jann Wenner#Bi-Weekly#Philadelphia#8000
Rolling Stone#Jann Wenner#Bi-Weekly#London#10000
The Economist#John Micklethwait#Weekly#New York#42000
The Economist#John Micklethwait#Weekly#Washington#29000
Nature#Philip Campbell#Weekly#Pittsburg#4000
Nature#Philip Campbell#Weekly#Berlin#6000

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9000 Rolling Stone"
```

9000 should be an integer value. And the last index jumps onto the next line because there's no # what should I do?

I believe this much code is sufficient

```
    static ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(); // Consists of lines of the text file
    static ArrayList<Magazine> bl = new ArrayList<Magazine>(); // Consists of Magazine objects

for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
                String result[] = al.get(i).split("\\#");
                for (int j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
                    System.out.println(result[0] + "1 " + result[1] + "2 " +  result[2] + "3 " +  result[3] + "4 "+  result[4]);
                    int num = Integer.parseInt(result[4]);
```

I'm having a spider sense somewhere close split("\#") but i dont know what...

Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/Vp9T6aSd

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Magazine {

    private String MagazineName;
    private String Publisher;
    private String Frequency;
    private String City;
    private String objectName = "mg" + loopCount;
    private int Distribution;
    private static int loopCount = 0;

    static ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(); // Consists of lines of the text file
    static ArrayList<Magazine> bl = new ArrayList<Magazine>(); // Consists of Magazine objects

    private static void readData() throws FileNotFoundException {
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File(
                "/Users/henrydang/Desktop/Zines.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            sc.useDelimiter("\\n");
            String line = sc.next();
            System.out.println(line);
            al.add(line);
            Magazine objectName;

            for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
                String result[] = al.get(i).split("#");
                for (int j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
                    System.out.println(result[0] + "1 " + result[1] + "2 " +  result[2] + "3 " +  result[3] + "4 "+  result[4]);
                    int num = Integer.parseInt(result[4]);

                    objectName = new Magazine();
                    objectName.setMagazine(result[0]);
                    objectName.setPublisher(result[1]);
                    objectName.setFrequency(result[2]);
                    objectName.setCity(result[3]);
                    objectName.setDistribution(num);
                    bl.add(objectName);             
                }

            }
            loopCount++;
            sc.close();

        }
    }

    public Magazine() {

    }

    public void setMagazine(String name) {
        this.MagazineName = name;
    }

    public void setPublisher(String name) {
        this.Publisher = name;
    }

    public void setFrequency(String name) {
        this.Frequency = name;
    }

    public void setCity(String name) {
        this.City = name;
    }

    public void setDistribution(int num) {
        this.Distribution = num;
    }

    public String getMagazine() {
        return MagazineName;
    }

    public String getPublisher() {
        return Publisher;
    }

    public String getFrequency() {
        return Frequency;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return City;
    }

    public int getDistribution() {
        return Distribution;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
        readData();
    }

}
```

EDIT: more information
SOLVED: The text file had endings with /r/n instead of "/n"

Comment: *"I believe this much code is sufficient"* For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: What is the `j` loop for? It appears to be redundant.

Comment: Henry, don't edit questions by hitting the back button.  Instead use the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14303739/edit) below the question.

Comment: please add `System.out.println(al.get(i))` in your code. I am sure you include text from the line below

Comment: @Henry Wrong assumption - the suffix will still be added as last split. The problem **MUST** be in `al.get(i)`

Comment: `sc.useDelimiter("\\n");`  Probably better to replace `"\\n"` with `System.getProperty("line.separator")`.

Comment: He seems to be on a *nix system based on his file path. Since you are using a scanner @Henry you can just do sc.nextLine(); maybe that solves it? The output of `al.get(i)` or your file `Zines.txt` (as an attachment somehow) will solve the problem for sure.

Comment: @Andrew Replacing "\\n" with System.getProperty("line.separator") gives the same output.

Comment: @Henry - This code seems buggy - are you aware that for each line you read, you create all the objects for all the lines from scratch? 1 line = 1 object, 2 lines = 3 objects, 3 lines = 5 objects, 4 lines = 9 objects etc ...

Comment: @Sanchit changing from next to nextFile() doesn't change the output but by adding a # at the end of each line in the text file solves the problem.

Comment: @RonK you're right, been a bit to hasty, let me reconstructure this :S

Comment: @Henry the problem is that your scanner is getting 2 lines at once somehow when you do sc.next(), we want to help you fix that issue. So we either require the file as an attachment (so we can check the `\n`'s) or the output of `al.get(i)`

Comment: @Sanchit i will provide the output i get from al.get(i)

Comment: @Henry Just for the sake of argument - try using `sc.hasNextLine` and `sc.nextLine` instead and see if it solves your problem

Comment: I think your file has line endings with '\r\n' instead of '\n' I fiddled around with it a bit and that is the only possible cause. Can you double check this @Henry? Check the settings on your text editor.

Also I moved your sc.close() outside the loop, other than that, your code worked flawlessly.

Comment: Oh...just checked it and you're right, and now i get the right variable i want. Thanks for having patience with me. ^^

Comment: I hate you @Henry. j/k. Glad we got it sorted out. Just using hasNextLine() and NOT specifying ANY delimiters will solve this problem of worrying about `\r\n` vs `\n`. Let me put this in an answer for you so that your percentage doesn't go down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Henry...

A couple of problems with your code:

1. sc.close() was being called inside the `while (sc.hasNext()){}` loop.
2. sc.setDelimiter() being called inside the sc.hasNext() is sort of very shady but it works I guess as you call `.next()` after setting the delimiter.
3. We have figured out that the problem was with the input file itself and not your code per-se. Always double check your files if you are writing some platform speciic code (such as with your `\n` delimiter).

And here is your code with the proper / ideal way I'd use a scanner for your code:

```
private static void readData() throws FileNotFoundException {  
  java.io.File file = new java.io.File("Zines.txt");  
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);  
  while (sc.hasNextLine()) {  
    String line = sc.nextLine();  
  }  
  sc.close();  
}
```

Hope it all helped!

Edit: Ignore the comments conversation below. We are not mad, I redid the answer.

Comment: Why not? That's the only way `System.out.println(result[0] + "1 " + result[1] + "2 " +  result[2] + "3 " +  result[3] + "4 "+  result[4])` line could possibly work.

Comment: This is not the core issue. Check the String used to call `parseInt()`.`"9000 Rolling Stone"` which means the two consecutive lines are together.

Comment: So basically the `al.get(i)` that he told us is wrong. I see why we are all waiting and editing now.

Comment: @Sanchit However, I revert my downvote - I thought `#` is always to be escaped in regex. However I tried it and I was wrong.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev and I have now learned that `'\\#'` = (real) `'\#'` and `'#'` are the same thing when it comes to java and regex. I +1'd your request for al.get(i) :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try:

```
String result[] = al.get(i).split("#\\s*");
```

it will separate the substrings whenever a "#" occurs.